# Rails: How can an instance variable declared in a controller accessible in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby instance variables are accessible to a single object. But in rails, if I declare an instance variable in a controller, it is still accessible in the views. What is the architecture behind this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, your controller calls `render` which renders your templates. So, the template code is being run within the scope of the controller instance. Therefore, you can use any instance variables declared.